# Defining type as a reference in golang

Tags: oop, go

To my surprise this block

```
type Object *struct{
  X int
}
```

compiles in golang. However, I don't know how to create an instance of the underlying struct.

Functionally, what I wanted to achieve is to remove all the stars from all type signatures without hacks (redefining the type and other tricks). This would make the type/structs very much like Java classes.

The question is - is this construction supported in golang? Or should I stick to putting stars everywhere?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. First note that the empty struct is treated special. Your question seems to be about other stuff than the empty struct. Second: No, you will have to deal with pointers in Go. Third: The language is called Go, not golang.

Comment: You should stick to "putting stars everywhere". In Go named pointer types are, AFAICT, useless and you most likely won't need them, just ignore the fact that it's possible to define them. (Also this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/5EIKbImHRqs)

Comment: I added an attribute to avoid special cases. The question is about the * before struct in type definition. It defines a reference, but I don't know if I can use it in meaningful way.

Comment: @mkopriva many thanks, that's exactly what I asked about.

Comment: No it does not define a "reference". Do not thing about pointers as references: The y are not.

Comment: Use the following to create a value: `Object(&struct{ X int }{X: 1})` .  Go programs use pointers.  You will have an easier time writing Go code if you don't fight that fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass pointers around everywhere, you don't have to. You could just pass your structs around by value.

E.g.

Define your struct as:

```
type Object struct{
  X int
}
```

And then define your functions as:

```
func DoStuffToObject(obj Object) {
    // Do things with obj here
}
```

There's nothing wrong with passing around objects by value if that's what you wish to do.